# I have a php/html which shows me a text zone with submit.how to "delete" these forms

Tags: php, html

I have a php/html which shows me a text zone with submit.how to “delete” these forms after validation. For example, if I type John and then I press "Send", it must show "Hello John" without text zone and submit, on the same page. Thanks

```
<?php
echo '<form method="post" action="menu.php" >';
echo '<input type="text"  name="name"  size="10">';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Send">';
$name=$_POST['name'];

echo 'Hello'.$name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if the $_POST variable is set with the `isset()` function : if $_POST is set, display the sentence, otherwise display the form.